# Microsoft Access passing variables to VB from Form

Tags: sql, variables, ms-access, vba

I built a form with 2 combo boxes, one for Event and one for People. The two queries for the boxes include the Event_id and People_id but are not shown. The idea is to select the event from a drop down then add a person to attend the event. My problem is passing these two ID to the SQL update script.

Below is the VB; I receive a 424 error and calls the SQL as the area.

What's wrong?

```
    Private Sub Command15_Click()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database, sql As String, rCount As Integer

  Set dbs = CurrentDb

  sql = "INSERT INTO Whos_Going (Event_ID, Who_is_invited) " _
  & "VALUES(" & Event_id.Text & ", " & People_id.Text & ")"

  dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError

  rCount = dbs.RecordsAffected

If rCount > 0 Then
MsgBox "Person Added to Event"
'update listbox
conInfo.Requery
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With VBA you need to construct the valid sql statement. All string literals must be enclosed into `'`, all dates must be enclosed into `#`. In addition to that, if your string variable contains an apostrophe it needs to be replaced with `''`. The correct syntax will be:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Whos_Going (Event_ID, Who_is_invited) " _
    & "VALUES('" & Replace(Event_id.Text, "'", "''") & "', '" _
    & Replace(People_id.Text, "'", "''") & "')"
```

Comment: Cheers mare but still a 424 error are the variables right ? they are not shown on the screen in the form

Comment: Object required error. See here: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/questions/obj_required.php